# How to do A bindrequest and modify attribute at the same time

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm using unboundid for accesing LDAP I'm doing a bind request for the user, and also update a value for lastlogin. can I perfom this operation at the same time, or my process should be

```
BindRequest bindRequest = generateBindRequest(mail,password);

BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);

if(result == Ok)
=> actualize last login correct

if(result == OK)
=> actualize last login incorrect
```

Because I do not find other workflow like the one I showed

Comment: What schema are you using?

Comment: The user entry has custom objectclass from Oracle OAM, and person, top, and inetorgperson

Comment: I ask because some schemas maintain a last login time automatically. The password policy extension is one. If you don't have such a feature, what you ask is impossible. You can't bind and set attributes at the same time.